# Clustering a pandas dataframe with seaborn - overlapping labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm on Mac OS 10.10.2, Python 2.7.11, Seaborn 0.6.0, pandas 0.17.1, matplotlib 1.5.0. I'm running the following code to hierarchical clusterize a dataframe with `seaborn.clustermap`:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)
df['y'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)

L = []
for i in range(25):
    L.append('longlonglabel' + str(i))

df.index = L
sns.clustermap(df)
plt.show()
```

which returns:

[image]

I have some troubles with the overlapping labels on the row side. According to the examples provided [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), the default behaviour should set the labels horizontally. Is this a bug? Anyone can reproduce it?

Comment: The labels show up properly when I run it.

Comment: Thanks for trying that! May you show your python, pandas etc version?

Comment: pandas (0.17.1);
seaborn (0.6.0);matplotlib (1.4.3);Python 2.7.10;osx 10.9.4.

Comment: So maybe the issue is related to matplotlib 1.5.0...

Comment: I have the same output as you @FabioLamanna (vertically oriented labels) with the following config : matplotlib 1.5.0 / pandas 0.17.0 / seaborn 0.6.0 / python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to set the label horizontally is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)
df['y'] = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)

L = []
for i in range(25):
    L.append('longlonglabel' + str(i))

df.index = L
cg = sns.clustermap(df)

# Iterate over the labels
for text in cg.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels():
    text.set_rotation('horizontal')

plt.show()
```